# AWS credentials with Identity pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

How can I pass the Cognito user's idToken to Amplify.configure() , cause the users have to be authenticated, not as a guest user. So Instead of getting an unauthenticated identityId, How do I get an authenticated Id by setting in the aws amplify configure.

For sign-in and sign-up we are not using Amplify instead we are using Rest API

Currently I'm sending Object to configure as follows,

```
{
    Auth: {
        identityPoolId: const.identityPoolId,
        IdentityId: 'us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyzzzzzz',
        region: 'us-east-1'
    },
    Analytics: {
        disabled: false,
        autoSessionRecord: true,
        AWSPinpoint: {
            appId: PinpointId,
            region: 'us-east-1',
            bufferSize: 1000,
            flushInterval: 5000,
            flushSize: 100,
            resendLimit: 3
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks